# SharePoint 2010 multiple report viewer webparts - very slow

Tags: 2010, reporting-services

I have 7 report viewer webparts on one SharePoint page. It takes ages to load all of them, if I open the RDL directly, the report loads within 2 seconds. If I remove 6 web parts (thus, only 1 web part left) from the page, the web part loads very fast too.

How can I increase the loading time? All those updatepanels that are created in ReportViewer webpart (I checked using reflector) for lazy loading / AJAX calls / etc cause part of the trouble, I assume. Disabling viewstate is not an option, this is breaking the web parts.

Comment: Is this a single server farm or a low-end server being used as a WFE?

Comment: Two-server farm with medium-end WFE. Only 1 report runs very fast, more than 3 causes heavy delays. Although production has faster servers, at this environment it should be faster than it is now. The page takes more than 80 seconds to load...